# How should I order an if statement?

Tags: java, c++, c

[I thought this would have been asked already, but I can't find an answer].

When writing an `if` statement, should the thing I'm comparing *against* come first or second? (I am specifically curious about both `C / C++` and `Java`).

Does it matter, or is it just stylistic? (Convention seems to be "variable first, value second").

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 5;

    if ( 5 == x ) {
        std::cout << "X == 5, true." << std::endl;
    }
    if ( x == 5 ) {
        std::cout << "5 == X, true." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

> X == 5, true.
>   5 == X, true.

so there doesn't *appear* to be any difference. Are there subtleties I'm missing?

Comment: Annoying statements of the second kind Yoda conditions are called :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Brilliant, I didn't see the linked question. Once you know what it's called, it's easy to search for.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight nice one the comment is

Comment: In C++, there *can* be a difference if operator overloading is involved. (But that won't be an issue in your particular example.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are called [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) and to my knowledge the main idea is to guard against accidental assignment (i.e. you can't assign to literals).

Yes, worth mentioning that something like `if (a = 5)` where `a` is not a `bool` is not allowed in languages such as Java (though OK in C/C++), but as the Wikipedia article points out it is still possible to guard against unwanted behavior:

It can also solve some types of unsafe null behavior.

```
String myString = null;
if (myString.equals("foobar")) { /* ... */ }
// This causes a NullPointerException in Java
```

With Yoda Conditions:

```
String myString = null;
if ("foobar".equals(myString)) { /* ... */ }
// This is false, as expected
```

Comment: +1 for `equals` example - that's a basic trap most people fall :)

Comment: But `if(foo = true)` would be allowed in Java.

Comment: @Jeffrey yes, should clarify that bools are an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Putting the constant first (aka "Yoda style") prevents problems from a simple typo:

```
if (x = 5) // if (x == 5) was intended
```

...still compiles but does the wrong thing (though most current compilers will warn about the  problem).

```
if (5 = x) // if (5 == x) was intended
```

...absolutely cannot compile on anything even approaching a properly functioning compiler.

Comment: Yoda style will benefit only for c/c++ as in java `x=5` will not compile

Comment: yeah in java too, think if some one want to compare and put `x=5` will compile and don't know about his miss, if put in yoda way not gonna to compile :)

Comment: @Bingo Yoda style benefits Java with boolean expressions: `if(foo = true)` compiles.

Comment: @Jeffrey yeah that's the case. Good Point

Comment: Who writes `foo == true` anyway? (And FWIW, C and C++ compilers warn against this so there isn't a solid reason to prefer less readable code)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference. It doesn't matter. Do whatever you like. Personally I'd do:

`x == 5`

Because it reads better (or so I think). `5 == x` just doesn't sound right. But again, personal opinion.

I think you'll find that most people do `x == 5` because you are comparing `x`, rather than comparing `5`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are ok.
But it is more accepted to do so when the parameter on left side.
example:

```
if ( x == 5 )
```

Anyway. it doesn't matter, do whatever you pleased and feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score -4):

In most cases you'll find the common practice is to have the variable come first because the operator *==* means assignment and here you are assigning the value *5* so it only makes sense to have the variable come first.

Your if statement should then look like this:

```
    if ( 5 == x ) {
        std::cout << "X == 5, true." << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: operator == is *not* assignment.

Comment: The word you were looking for is "equality", _not_ "assignment".